# Jquery collapsing menu in wordpress (slight glitch)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

So I'm making a website using wordpress: http://www.baxtersresume.com/wordpress-3.9.1/wordpress/about/

I'm playing with the menu jquery to get the right effect and I think I've almost got it but I need a bit of help. If you look at the site you'll notice when you open the bottom submenu by mousing over and then re-enter the menu from the bottom with the pointer it will close. That's what I'm trying to avoid. Here's the script so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".page_item ul, .sub-menu").hide();
var current; 
var currentsub;

jQuery(".page_item ul, .sub-menu").prev().mouseenter( function() {
current = jQuery(this);
currentsub = jQuery(this).next(); 

currentsub.slideDown();
});

/*jQuery(".header__content").mouseleave( function() {
jQuery(".page_item ul, .sub-menu").slideUp();
});*/

jQuery(".menu-item-object-page, .menu-item-has-children").mouseenter( function() {
if (current != jQuery(this) && currentsub != jQuery(this)) {
currentsub.slideUp();

};

});
});
```

What can I do here?

edit* (Solved! JSfiddle with the html)
http://jsfiddle.net/tu965j0d/1/

Comment: Please post your HTML too, and if possible make a JSFiddle. As an aside, you should look into using `.stop()` to prevent queuing on your animations on the gallery.

Comment: stop() is definitely something I needed to use. That was a big part of the glitchyness I was experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following would be a starting point for you. Simply using selectors to determine those elements you want to slideUp/slideDown, and exclude children of the target of the mouseEnter event?

```
$(function () {
    $('.sub-menu').hide().parent().mouseenter(function(){
        $('.sub-menu').not($(this).find('.sub-menu')).stop(true, true).slideUp();
        $(this).find('.sub-menu').slideDown();
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tu965j0d/

**Edit**: There's also a number of accordian menu libraries and tutorials out there, might be useful? For example, [this little tutorial](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/vertical-accordion-menu-using-jquery-css3) using some nice CSS3 transitions.

Comment: That was perfect! I barely had to change a thing for my own purposes because you wrote it so eloquently. I learned a few things dare I say. Thank you. 

Only thing I added was :
    $('.menu-item-object-page').mouseenter(function () {
 $('.sub-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp();
    });
Just to close the sub-menu's when touching other elements of the menu.